# How to fix ESLint: React Hook React.useEffect has a missing dependency error

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, eslint, native-base

I have a functional component that needs to call a function every time the error changes, however giving `toast` as a dependency is causing infinite execution of `useEffect` body.
I do not want to disable eslint rule because of https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6880#issuecomment-485912528 by Dan Abromov

```js
function SignUpForm() {
  const navigation = useNavigation<NativeStackScreenProps<RootStackParamList, "Signup">["navigation"]>()
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch()
  const firebaseAuthError = useAppSelector((state) => state.auth.error)
  const toast = useToast()

  const [formState, setFormState] = useState<Form>({
    email: "",
    emailError: "",
    password: "",
    passwordError: "",
    isPasswordVisible: false,
    passwordConfirm: "",
    passwordConfirmError: "",
    isPasswordConfirmVisible: false,
  })

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (firebaseAuthError) {
      toast.show({
        title: "Authentication error",
        description: firebaseAuthError,
        duration: 2000,
      })
    }

    return () => toast.closeAll()
  }, [firebaseAuthError]) // for this line eslint yells: ESLint: React Hook React.useEffect has a missing dependency: 'toast'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.(react-hooks/exhaustive-deps)
}
```

Comment: one thing on this code you are doing wrong is never add condition on useEffect its not correct. kindly create a function then add this condition on this function and then call this function on useEffect.

Comment: if you need to disable it then add **// tslint:disable-next-line: no-console**.

Comment: **eslint src --ext=ts,tsx --fix .** this command resolve all eslint issue.

Comment: 1) Your first comment is not true. 2) I do not want to suppress the warning but fix it. 3) It's not something that eslint can auto-fix